# How to access TatSu parserinfo object

Tags: tatsu, grako

I've just started playing with TatSu and don't have much experience with it yet.  I'm successfully parsing a small COBOL code snippet, but would like to access the details that are produced when **parserinfo=True**. Would anyone have some sample code I can use for this?  Here's my code.  Thank you in advance.

from tatsu import parse, compile

cobbnf_file = open("cobfd.bnf", "r")
cobbnf = cobbnf_file.read()

cobtest_file = open("test.cob", "r")
cobtest = cobtest_file.read()

model = compile(cobbnf, "cobol")
ast = model.parse(cobtest, parseinfo=True, trace=False)

print(ast)

Comment: Please format the Python code? It would be good if you also included the grammar and the current output.